# servicestack redis, when using SetEntry, it will automatic generate a set with key "ids:+objectName" in redis db, how can I disable it?

Tags: redis, servicestack

when using SetEntry, it will automatic generate a set with key "ids:+ objectName" in redis db.

For example:
   typedClient.SetEntry("famyly:username:jhon",new Family {FatherName="Jhon",...});

a set with key name of "ids:Family" and a member like "2343443" will be automatic created in redis db,
and each time I update or modify the same key with SetEntry, the set of "ids:Family" will increment with an new auto generated member. And this set will grow extremely large if I update the key frequently.

How can I disable the auto generated set? this set seems useless for the current circumstances.

thanks

Comment: I can avoid the auto set by using SetEntryIfNotExists when create the key, and using RemoveEntry to delete the key and SetEntryIfNotExists to reset the key when update. But this is cumbersome, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem - I discovered that our database contained a couple dozen of these "ids:XXX" sets, each containing tens of millions of items, which were consuming significant amounts of memory.

The solution is to switch to untyped clients. You can still use typed *methods* on the client so you're really not giving up any type safety or automatic serialization at all. There's a couple ways to create clients; we tend to use the get-in-get-out `Exec` shortcuts on `RedisClientsManager`. You should be able to adapt this to the way you do it.

Typed client - creates "ids" sets:

```
// set:
redis.ExecAs<T>(c => c.SetEntry(key, value));

// get:
T value = redis.ExecAs<T>(c => c.GetValue(key));
```

Untyped client - no "ids" sets created:

```
// set:
redis.Exec(c => c.Set(key, value));

// get:
using (var cli = _redis.GetClient())
{
    T value = cli.Get<T>(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inferred auto-generated id's are when you use the high-level Redis Typed Client. Use the [IRedisClient.SetEntry](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L50) on the string-based RedisClient API instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this can be done by using IRedisClient.SetEntry, but in this way I have to serialize my object by myself. And IRedisTypedClient.SetEntry is designed to do this work. By the way it doesn't make senese to generate a set of ids in the context, I think it is for when you using Store or StoreAll.